# How to validate zend form in zf2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate

i make a form in zend framework2 but i cannot add capital letter how i validate capital A to Z in zf2?here is my code:

```
if(!$this->inputFilter)
    {
        $inputFilter = new InputFilter();
        $factory = new InputFactory();
        $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'username',
            'required'=>true,
            'filters'=> array(
                array('name'=>'StripTags'),
                array('name'=>'StringTrim')
            ),
            'validators'=>array(
                array('name'=>'Regex',
                    'options'=> array(
                        'pattern' => '/^[a-z0-9_.-]{1,50}+$/' // contain only a to z 0 to 9 underscore, hypen and dot and min 1 characters max 50
                    )
                )
            )
        )));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your pattern to be case-insensitive by adding the `i` modifier:

```
/^[a-z0-9_.-]{1,50}+$/i
```

Or explicitly allow capital letters:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]{1,50}+$/
```